# Concise conversion of List<List<Double>> to Array<DoubleArray>?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I wrote this in Kotlin:

```
        fun fromLists(cells: List<List<Double>>): Matrix {
            return Matrix(cells.stream()
                .map { x -> x.toDoubleArray() }
                .toArray { i: Int -> Array(i, { k: Int -> DoubleArray(k) }) } )
        }
```

Is there any way to reduce repetition in this code?

(`Matrix` itself is uninteresting, it just wraps an `Array<DoubleArray>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val ex1: Array<DoubleArray> = cells.map { it.toDoubleArray() }.toTypedArray()

// this should be faster, it doesn't create extra List like the previous example
val ex2: Array<DoubleArray> = Array(cells.size) { i -> cells[i].toDoubleArray() }
```